# Sci-Fi/Fantasy Anime about a girl who turns into a world-destroyer

Tags: story-identification, anime

I seriously cannot remember any names or parts of the title, I apologize.
I first watched this anime at least 10-15 years ago (most likely between 2001 and 2008) online, when even the last few episodes hadn't been fully translated from Japanese to English at the time. It had subtitles, and may have been a fan translation rather than an official airing. It's a 'modern' fantasy where most of the world isn't aware of magic existing, I believe. This was also not a long series, with only about 12 episodes or so.

The main girl is 'prophesied' to save the world, so she goes to different ruins (?) where they are trying to gather these gem like fragments studded into silver-colored shields that will float around and protect the main girl. However, when all the fragments are collected, it turns out the girl and her friends were lied to, and when the gems activate they turn the girl into a gigantic monster who tries to destroy the world. She is trapped inside the monster. Her friends stop her and defeat the villain who was pulling the strings in the end (because of friendship and love? - one of those cheesy ones).

The main character is a girl, but there is at least 1 other girl and 1 boy in the group of teenagers the story focuses on. I'm pretty sure they were in high school and wore generic uniforms (blue or grey?). But they didn't spend much time in class or with their classmates (or it wasn't important enough to the story to remember). The main group never exceeded 5 characters, and I really only vaguely remember the main three: The main girl was more petite and had short to medium-length hair (not blonde or red), and had a quieter and more shy personality. The guy friend was very tall and also fairly quiet, while the friend who was a girl was more friendly. I think the guy had short, greyish hair, while the girl had longer hair. There wasn't a romance, but it did feel like it hinted the guy and girl friends were interested in each other. The MC had been alone before being told she was special, and so friendship is important to her.

This was one of those series that had pacing issues, where even though there's a limited number of artifacts (around 12 or so), rather than space out 1 artifact per episode, most of the series is filler and then in the last 2-3 episodes they get all of the artifacts very quickly and rush to the climax.

There's an episode where they go on a picnic, keeping the thermos and the picnic basket in an interdimensional space. There may have also been a floating island/castle (where some kind of prophet/wizard/deity? resided) and a battle in the sky near the end, right before they collect the last of the artifacts.

I could have mis-remembered a few things above, but I do remember the outro music being fantastic!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Night Wizard!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Wizard!), 2007.

> Night Wizard. A term given to those whose mission it is to protect the world from impending darkness. Renji Hiiragi is one such Night Wizard, who is constantly called on missions, even though all he wants is to be able to go to school and graduate. However, his latest order was to protect Elis Shiho, who is a new transfer student at his academy. Being dragged into the Astronomy Club by Renji's childhood friend, Kureha Akabane on her first day at school, Elis soon realizes that she too, has the power to become a night wizard, after retrieving the Jewel of Affection. Along with Renji and Kureha, Elis now begins her fight and her new life, as a Night Wizard, both to collect the six other Jewels and to protect the world from eternal darkness.

[Episode 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Night_Wizard_episodes#Episode_list):

> As Renji, Elis, Kureha, and Akari go to school, Anzelotte brings them to her castle, where she reveals that the Jewel of Hope is in Saturn's rings. As she approaches Saturn with her wizard fleet, a horde of Emulators under Bell Zephyr's command appears. Anzelotte dispatches Renji, Elis, and Kureha to find the jewel, and prepares to attack the Emulators. However, the Demon Lord Lion Gunta predicts all of Anzelotte's ships' movements, and the Emulators take the advantage. Bell Zephyr then goes into battle, and tears through the wizards' defenses. She claims the Jewel of Hope, but a distraction by Akari allows Elis to claim the Jewel of Hope, something Lion comments she was unable to predict. As the jewel joins her bracelet, the jewels turn red, and a gigantic energy exudes from Elis, destroying most of both fleets. Elis then begins to destroy everything around her until Renji calms her, with Elis tearfully asking what she is doing. Anzelotte then realizes that Elis is Shaimal.